# Store a variable while playing several macros

Tags: global-variables, imacros

In imacros, macro1 extracts a text and it is stored as a variable VAR1.

Then at the end of macro1, macro2 is called, then macro3, macro4 etc...

VAR1 should be used in ALL macros, but the variable is reinitialized when macro1 is over, and another macro is called. The value of VAR1 is then 'undefined'.

Any way to get around this limitation ?

macro1.iim :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:blabla EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=generic/macro2.iim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the '!CLIPBOARD' variable:

```
' the line for 'macro1.iim'
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}

' the line for 'macro2.iim'
SET !VAR1 {{!CLIPBOARD}}
```

Also for iim-code you may store (write and read) variables in a temporal txt-file. (As to js-scripts there is a special way to do that as well.)

Comment: Using the Clipboard works great, thanks. 2nd alternative is also good to know !